# What happens inside this duct?

Tags: wiring, cables, panel

[image]

At the top are wires coming out of a terminal block. On the left are gray tubes running into a cabinet full of sensors, motors, etc.

Are these gray tubes conduits or cables? What is happening at the transition point?

I would like to open it up, but I don't have this in my possession.

Comment: The duct is just an organizer, it helps keep things tidy. They are used a lot in industrial control panels.

Comment: I'm not sure we'd be able to tell just from that photo. It could just be a mechanical shroud to prevent snagging or damaging the wires with nothing interesting inside or there could be splices, junctions, or active components. I'd guess the former is more likely, but that's a guess and the device would need to be investigated to confirm.

Comment: The "gray tubes" are cables. Each cable consists of an outer sheath (the gray bit) which encloses a number of individual wires. Each individual wire also has its own insulation.

Comment: It’s just a cable tray.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

*Figure 1. Slotted cable trunking used in industrial panel wiring. Image source: [ABB](https://new.abb.com/low-voltage/products/wire-cable-management/wiring-duct-trunking).*

[image]

*Figure 2. In this photo we can (barely) see individual wires entering the trunking from behind while double-insulated multi-core cables enter from the left.*

[image]

*Figure 3. In this zoom-in we can just about see the multicore cable has been stripped back to allow access to the individual cores which are taken out through the trunking slots. You can also see some handwritten cable identification markings through the slots.*

Comment: You're a saint.